Common Base Kustomize File For different versions of Application
I want to have a common kustomize file for different release versions of my application such that I can utilize the repeated resource
For example lets say this is my version 1.1.5 kustomize file
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: numaflow-system

resources:
  - upstream/numaflow-server.yaml
  - upstream/minimal-crds.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-aggregate-to-admin.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/wavefront-collector.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-aggregate-to-edit.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-aggregate-to-view.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-ingress.yaml

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - patches/numaflow-server.yaml
  - ../mixins/patches/numaflow-server-role.yaml
  - ../mixins/patches/numaflow-service.yaml

images:
  - name: quay.io/numaproj/numaflow
    newName: docker.com/quay-rmt/numaproj/numaflow

And this is versions 1.0.0 kustomize file
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: numaflow-system

resources:
  - upstream/numaflow-server.yaml
  - upstream/minimal-crds.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-aggregate-to-admin.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/wavefront-collector.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-aggregate-to-edit.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-aggregate-to-view.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-ingress.yaml

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - ../mixins/patches/numaflow-server.yaml
  - patches/numaflow-server-rbac-config.yaml
  - ../mixins/patches/numaflow-service.yaml

Now I wanto have a  common kustomization file which can include repeated resources and  patchesStrategicMerge something like below
resources:
  - mixins/resources/

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - mixins/patches/numaflow-server.yaml
  - mixins/patches/numaflow-server-role.yaml
  - mixins/patches/numaflow-service.yaml

so my version file should look something like this
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: numaflow-system

resources:
- upstream/numaflow-server.yaml
- upstream/minimal-crds.yaml
-   ../../base

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - patches/numaflow-server.yaml
 

Problem - Above approach and similar approach doesn't seem to work ,and gives build error
My directory structure looks like this
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── mixins
│       ├── patches
│       │   ├── numaflow-server-role.yaml
│       │   ├── numaflow-server.yaml
│       │   └── numaflow-service.yaml
│       └── resources
│           ├── kustomization.yaml
│           ├── numaflow-aggregate-to-admin.yaml
│           ├── numaflow-aggregate-to-edit.yaml
│           ├── numaflow-aggregate-to-view.yaml
│           ├── numaflow-ingress.yaml
│           └── wavefront-collector.yaml
└── versions
    ├── v0.10.1
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   └── upstream
    │       ├── minimal-crds.yaml
    │       └── numaflow-server.yaml
    ├── v1.0.0
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   ├── patches
    │   │   └── numaflow-server-rbac-config.yaml
    │   └── upstream
    │       ├── minimal-crds.yaml
    │       └── numaflow-server.yaml
    └── v1.1.5
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        ├── patches
        │   └── numaflow-server.yaml
        └── upstream
            ├── minimal-crds.yaml
            └── numaflow-server.yaml

I expect to have a centrallized kustomize file that can include the duplicate resource and while creating the kustomize for the new version I can utilize the base kustomize file.
Any help would be appreciated.

Related question on same issue -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78456604/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-central-patch-for-multiple-kustomization-yaml-files

"Above approach and similar approach doesn't seem to work ,and gives build error" -- could you update this question to include an [mcve] that reproduces the error? None of the examples shown here are making use of the versions/ hierarchy. The overall structure looks fine; having a specific problem to look at would make it easier to develop a useful answer.

I am not absolutely confident as I have not tried this myself yet, but give following a try. Also, apologies for bad formatting of code.
base/kustomization.yaml:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: numaflow-system

resources:
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-aggregate-to-admin.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/wavefront-collector.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-aggregate-to-edit.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-aggregate-to-view.yaml
  - ../mixins/resources/numaflow-ingress.yaml

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - ../mixins/patches/numaflow-server-role.yaml
  - ../mixins/patches/numaflow-service.yaml

Version-Specific KustomizationsVersion 1.1.5:
versions/1.1.5/kustomization.yaml:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: numaflow-system

resources:
  - ../../upstream/numaflow-server.yaml
  - ../../upstream/minimal-crds.yaml
  - ../../base

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - patches/numaflow-server.yaml

images:
  - name: quay.io/numaproj/numaflow
newName: docker.com/quay-rmt/numaproj/numaflow

versions/1.0.0/kustomization.yaml:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: numaflow-system

resources:
  - ../../upstream/numaflow-server.yaml
  - ../../upstream/minimal-crds.yaml
  - ../../base

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - patches/numaflow-server-rbac-config.yaml

Your directory structure would look like this:
├── base
│   └── kustomization.yaml
├── mixins
│   ├── patches
│   │   ├── numaflow-server-role.yaml
│   │   ├── numaflow-service.yaml
│   └── resources
│       ├── numaflow-aggregate-to-admin.yaml
│       ├── wavefront-collector.yaml
│       ├── numaflow-aggregate-to-edit.yaml
│       ├── numaflow-aggregate-to-view.yaml
│       └── numaflow-ingress.yaml
├── upstream
│   ├── numaflow-server.yaml
│   └── minimal-crds.yaml
└── versions
    ├── 1.0.0
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   └── patches
    │       └── numaflow-server-rbac-config.yaml
    └── 1.1.5
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        └── patches
            └── numaflow-server.yaml

Explanation:
The base/kustomization.yaml file includes all the common resources and patches.Each version-specific kustomization references the base directory in its resources field, which includes the common configurations.The version-specific kustomizations add their unique resources and patches as needed.
