Is there a way to use a central patch for multiple kustomization.yaml files?
Say I have 2 kustomization.yaml files, where each one defines a resource of the same kind/namespace/name. But I want to have a single patch that applies to each.
Directory structure:
- patches
- directory1
  - kustomization.yaml
  - service-a.yaml
- directory2
  - kustomization.yaml
  - service-a.yaml

directory1/kustomization.yaml:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: numaflow-system

resources:
  - service-a.yaml # defines Service "Service-A" in namespace "Namespace-A"

directory2/kustomization.yaml:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: numaflow-system

resources:
  - service-a.yaml # defines Service "Service-A" in namespace "Namespace-A"

In my patches directory I want to have a patch for "Service-A" that applies to both. We can also imagine that there are many more patches in that same directory for other resources that are each defined in directory1 and directory2.
Is there any way to reference that patches directory from each kustomization.yaml file? Looking to do this in a way that doesn't require having to separately list all individual patch files in each kustomization.yaml file.
We attempted to update a kustomization.yaml to include:
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - ../patches

But perhaps a directory can't be referenced there?

It would help to have more information here. How does service-a.yaml differ between the two directories? What are the contents of the patch? There are probably several ways of approaching this problem, and the details matter.

I was trying to create a simple example by pretending it was just one service. Realistically, both service-a.yaml files would consist of many Resource definitions. Realistically, there would not only be 2 directories of these, but rather one for every release of code. And trying to find a way to not have to separately list out every patch file in each kustomization.yaml

Basically, our code base consists of both our code and the manifest of resources we need to run. This slowly changes with each release of software. we have a kustomization.yaml for each release and a set of patches that is deemed to work with every release.

tl;dr: You can do what you want using kustomize components, but I am worried that this solution is plastering over a problem caused by the organization of your repository.
Given a layout like this:
.
├── directory1
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── service-a.yaml
├── directory2
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── service-a.yaml
└── patches
    └── mypatch
        └── kustomization.yaml

Where patches/mypatch/kustomization.yaml looks like (note the apiVersion and kind):
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component

patches:
- patch: |-
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: postgresql
      labels:
        patched_label: is very exciting

We can write then write directory1/kustomization.yaml like this:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: mynamespace

resources:
- service-a.yaml

components:
- ../patches/mypatch

And similarly for directory2.
So assuming that directory1/service-a.yaml looks like this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgresql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: postgresql
    port: 5432
  selector:
    name: postgresql

Running kustomize build directory1 will produce as output:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    patched_label: is very exciting
  name: postgresql
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  ports:
  - name: postgresql
    port: 5432
  selector:
    name: postgresql

How does that look?

What's the concern regarding the organization of the repository?

Typically, if I want to apply the same patch to multiple manifests, I would reverse the structure so the patch is applied at the outermost layer, rather than what we're doing here. But I don't know enough about the organization of your repository to know whether or not that would be appropriate.
